# piecewise regression with the segmented function : starting psi out of the admissible range

Tags: r, lm, piecewise

My data :

```
require(segmented)
y <- c(0.079, 0.079, 0.079, 0.080, 0.080, 0.081, 0.081, 0.081, 0.081, 0.081, 0.081, 0.082, 0.083, 0.084, 0.086, 0.088, 0.088, 0.088, 0.088, 0.088)
x <- c(1443991015, 1443994615, 1443998215, 1444001815, 1444005415, 1444009015, 1444012615, 1444016215, 1444019815, 1444023415, 1444027015, 1444030615, 1444034215, 1444037815, 1444041415, 
           1444045015, 1444048615, 1444052215, 1444055815, 1444059415)
```

nb : x data were POSIXct dates which are now converted to "numeric" format.

My linear model :

```
lin.mod <- lm(y ~ x)
```

With the output :

```
    Call:
lm(formula = y ~ x)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)            x  
 -2.201e+02    1.525e-07
```

Now, I want to find breakpoint if it exists

I do :

```
segmented.mod <- segmented(obj = lin.mod, seg.Z = ~x, psi = 11)
```

But I returns me this error message :

```
    Error in segmented.lm(obj = lin.mod, seg.Z = ~dates, psi = 11) : 
  starting psi out of the admissible range
```

Comment: Either omit declaring `psi` or use a sane starting point, i.e., one that is in the range of x data values. `segmented` can't estimate breakpoints outside your data range, obviously.

Comment: Oh yeah, obviously ... Thank you. I must write psi = x[11] instead of psi = 11